# SQL hierarchical table: how to jump levels

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I need to extract data from a table (call it "T") and load it into another table via DML (i.e., `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` syntax).  Table T is a hierarchical table with 4 levels defined (level 4 being the lowest, and level 1 being the highest).  The essential table structure of table T is:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
   PK int
  ,parentID int
  ,level int
  ,attribute1 varchar(255)
  ,attribute2 varchar(255)
  ,.
   .
   .
  ,attributeN varchar(255)
);
```

Every row in this table maps to exactly 1 row in the level above it via parentID (to PK).  I need to effectively "flatten out" table T in my `SELECT`.  That is, for a given level 4 row, I need to select some attributes from this row, some attributes from its corresponding level 2 parent, and some attributes from its corresponding level 1 parent.  Obviously, I can easily do that with `JOIN`s on `parent.PK = child.parentID`.  However, a "level 3" parent doesn't always exist for every level 4 row.  For these situations, the level 4 row maps straight to a level 2 parent.  Still, I need to write just one DML template that can be used in all situations (both where the level 3 parent exists and where it does not).  How can I do this?  My base query (which I know is wrong) is:

```
SELECT
   level4.attribute1
  ,level2.attributeN
  ,level1.attribute2
FROM
  T AS level4
INNER JOIN
  T AS level3
ON
  level3.PK = level4.parentID
INNER JOIN
  T AS level2
ON
  level2.PK = level3.parentID
INNER JOIN
  T AS level1
ON
  level1.PK = level2.parentID
WHERE
  level4.PK = 100
;
```

Comment: The reason you are struggling here is because your table lacks normalization. Attribute1, atribute2 etc is known as repeating groups and violates 1NF. What you should have is an architecture that allows for nesting like this. Adjacency lists are the most common way of handling this but nested sets are even better. Or there is also the hierarchyid datatype. Regardless you need to provide the ddl, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather your inner join fails when the level3 entry is missing, and you can't inner join level4 to level2, because that will only work in cases where the level3 entry is missing.  A UNION of two queries would be a possibility.  Another possibility would be to left join your way through the two possible paths to level2 and level1:

```
SELECT level4.attribute1, level2.attributeN, altlevel2.attributeN, level1.attribute2, altlevel1.attribute2 
FROM T AS level4 
LEFT JOIN T AS level3 ON level3.PK = level4.parentID 
LEFT JOIN T AS level2 ON level2.PK = level3.parentID 
LEFT JOIN T AS level1 ON level1.PK = level2.parentID 
LEFT JOIN T AS altlevel2 ON level2.PK = level4.parentID 
LEFT JOIN T AS altlevel1 ON level1.PK = level2.parentID 
WHERE level4.PK = 100;
```

The select list now includes two possible sets of attributes.  For a given record, one set of attributes will be null.  You could use CASE or COALESCE to boil that down into a select list with attributes in whatever form you would like to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Since level1 is the top of your hierarchy and is not dependent on a parent ID I would make that your original table and perform left joins onto that. I use left joins since inner joins will exclude the whole hierarchy if one of the levels is missing. To ensure that levels don't skip a level in the resulting dataset, I use where clauses for each level. Otherwise you could end up with level3 in the level 2 column since it skipped to parentID level1. Here is the resulting query.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
PK INT
,parentID int
,level int
,attribute1 varchar(255)
,attribute2 varchar(255)
)

INSERT @T VALUES
(1,0,1,'level1','1')
,(2,0,1,'level1','2')
,(3,0,1,'level1','3')
,(4,1,2,'level2','1')
,(5,2,2,'level2','2')
,(6,2,2,'level2','3')
,(7,4,3,'level3','1')
,(8,5,3,'level3','2')
,(9,6,3,'level3','3')
,(10,3,3,'level3','4')
,(11,9,4,'level4','1')
,(12,10,4,'level4','2')


SELECT
    level1.PK AS L1_PK
    ,level1.attribute1 AS L1_Attribute1
    ,level1.attribute2 AS L1_Attribute2
    ,level2.PK AS L2_PK
    ,level2.attribute1 AS L2_Attribute1
    ,level2.attribute2 AS L2_Attribute2
    ,level3.PK AS L3_PK
    ,level3.attribute1 AS L3_Attribute1
    ,level3.attribute2 AS L3_Attribute2
    ,level4.PK AS L4_PK
    ,level4.attribute1 AS L4_Attribute1
    ,level4.attribute2 AS L4_Attribute2
FROM @T AS level1
LEFT JOIN @T AS level2 ON
    level1.PK = level2.parentID
    AND level2.level = 2
LEFT JOIN @T AS level3 ON
    (level2.PK = level3.parentID
    OR level1.PK = level3.parentID)
    AND level3.level = 3
LEFT JOIN @T AS level4 ON
    (level3.PK = level4.parentID
    OR level2.PK = level4.parentID
    OR level1.PK = level4.parentID)
    AND level4.level = 4
WHERE level1.level = 1
```